# Javascript dropping square brackets on href change

Tags: javascript

This is weird. I have a bit of Javascript code that builds this query string:

```
var str = '/attorneys/?locations[]=70&locations[]=71&attorneyname=abc';
// p.s. in the real code, it actually builds str; it's not just declared like you see here :-)

window.location.href = str;
```

However, the browser is removing the square brackets and redirecting to:

`http://mysite.com/attorneys?locations=70&locations=71&attorneyname=abc`

Why is the browser/Javascript removing the square brackets? And how can I get them to stick?

Comment: I believe you need to html encode the brackets in order for them to transfer over a query string.

Comment: window.location.href = encodeURIComponent(str);

Comment: Why are you doing that anyway?

Comment: The brackets are to build a PHP array on the receiving page. (The actual code builds the query string, it doesn't just declare it like my demo code above.)

Comment: serverside code is probably PHP, and `[]` is how PHP accepts multi-value arguments for any single given field name.

Comment: @davidkonrad: Applying encodeURIComponent to the whole string will encode `/`, `?`, `=` and `&` as well … it should only be applied to the parameter name (and values as well, if necessary, but individually).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agree with the comments above, you need to encode the [] characters.

Try

`str = '/attorneys/?locations%5B%5D=70&locations%5B%5D=71&attorneyname=abc';`

more on encoding at http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp (includes list of some common character codes)

Comment: Meanwhile, it's a good idea that the OP will store locations as an array, and stringify or encode it.

Comment: @Terry Yes, I agree that you ideally should use the encode tools within code, however, as noted in comments above, that could create issues if not implemented carefully.  So, when you are only wanting particular pieces out of the url encoded, it may for some situations just be easier to just manually encode certain characters.  Sometimes a simple Find/Replace in your code can be quicker that running a url through a complex encoding function.  Agree with ideal, but, some situations manual is easier than coding.  Depends on user case and I don't know their full case, so gave simple answer.